# How to use multiple background CSS3 property with supersized jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery plugin supersized for full page background images (slideshow), I have setup everything correctly and it works perfectly.

Now what i want to achieve is, I was using multiple backgrounds earlier (CSS3), i..e transparent background over the original background for some textured effects and it looked cool, But after implementing the plugin, I'm unable to use multiple backgrounds.

Is there any way to use multiple backgrounds while retaining the bull page slideshow functionality (supersized plugin)?

If you didn't understand my question/problem just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I would do it using :after.

Here is what I added to the demo page

```
#supersized li:after { 
content: ""; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
background: #ff4e00; 
}
```

[Here it is in action](http://project.wecreatepixels.com/slideshow/demo.html)

So all you would need to do is edit the background on that part of the css. Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks mate :), Worked like a charm, used #supersized:after instead of #supersized li:after